# How do i install a react-native debug build to device with production-like optimized performance?

Tags: react-native

I want to use my app on my phone with smooth animation and production-like performance, but i want it to show red screen whenever error happens and to be possible to debug this app with remote-chrome-debugging. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you can just open the developer menu by shaking the device or emulator, and in Dev Settings, uncheck 'JS Dev Mode'. Also you can tweak other options if you are interested. As for iOS, I am not entirely sure how you can do it.